# Syntax error android sqlite: near "group"

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the exception shown by logcat window

```
06-08 11:25:55.532 8480-8480/example.com.shareit E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "group": syntax error      
06-08 11:25:55.542 8480-8480/example.com.shareit E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting amount=100 share1=0 share2=100 share3=0 paid2=0 share4=0 paid3=0 description=Food paid1=100 paid4=0 group=4 date=6/8/2016
06-08 11:25:55.542 8480-8480/example.com.shareit E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(amount,share1,share2,share3,paid2,share4,paid3,description,paid1,paid4,group,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Hope Someone Understands by this and this is my InsertContact()

```
public long insertContact(int amount, String description, String date, int paid1, int paid2,int paid3,int paid4, int share1, int share2,int share3,int share4,long group) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

    initialValues.put(KEY_PAID1, paid1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PAID2, paid2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PAID3, paid3);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PAID4, paid4);

    initialValues.put(KEY_SHARE1, share1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SHARE2, share2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SHARE3, share3);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SHARE4, share4);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GROUP, group);


    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

and this is where I am calling this method

```
public void saveBill(View view) {

    description = ETdescription.getText().toString();
    date = TVdate.getText().toString();
    amount = Integer.parseInt(ETamount.getText().toString());
    paid1 = Integer.parseInt(ETpaid1.getText().toString());
    paid2 = Integer.parseInt(ETpaid2.getText().toString());
    paid3 = Integer.parseInt(ETpaid3.getText().toString());
    paid4 = Integer.parseInt(ETpaid4.getText().toString());
    share1 = Integer.parseInt(ETshare1.getText().toString());
    share2 = Integer.parseInt(ETshare2.getText().toString());
    share3 = Integer.parseInt(ETshare3.getText().toString());
    share4 = Integer.parseInt(ETshare4.getText().toString());
    sumPaid = paid1 + paid2 + paid3 + paid4;
    sumShare = share1 + share2 + share3 + share4;

    if (a == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if ((amount == sumPaid) && (amount == sumShare)) {
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
            //---add a contact---
            db.open();
            long id = db.insertContact(amount, description, date, paid1, paid2, paid3, paid4, share1, share2, share3, share4, ++index);
            //id = db.insertContact("Mary Jackson", "mary@jackson.com");
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sum of Shares or Paid is not equal to total amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please share your table structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**group**" This is causing problem. Try using *mGroup*(or anything else) instead of group.

Reason: group is a reserved word ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) about group by clause) in sql.

```
SELECT name, sum(price) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY name
```

So you cannot use GROUP or group.

So your method should be:

```
    public long insertContact(int amount, String description, String date, 
int paid1, int paid2,int paid3,
int paid4, int share1, int share2,
int share3,int share4,long mGroup){

    //Put code here.

     initialValues.put(KEY_GROUP, mGroup);

    }
```

**EDIT**
Also if you have `KEY_GROUP = "group";` defined. Change that too to something else. One last point. Don't use **date** either. It is also reserved.

Best of luck.

Comment: I love It!!!!! It solved my problem and my app would be soon up on play store. Its all a help from you. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you using group as a column name in your customers table?, the problems seems to be the usage of 'date' and 'group' as column names, since both of them are reserved words. 
Try to modify the column names to date1 and group1 for example.